# give up (the) hope

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

1. I'm not ready to give up (the) hope of seeing him again.
2. I still haven't given up (the) hope that he might come back.

Would including "the" make the sentences more or less natural?

Comment: Why not say: I am not willing to give up hope of seeing him again. "The" is redundant.

Comment: "to give up hope" or similarly "to lose hope" is generally a fixed expression. The word "the" shouldn't be used here.

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+the+hope+of+being%2Chave+hope+of+being%2Chave+a+hope+of+being&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20the%20hope%20of%20being%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20hope%20of%20being%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20hope%20of%20being%3B%2Cc0) showing that in a context like *Robinson Crusoe knew he didn't have **the / a / [nothing]** hope of being rescued*, it's perfectly valid to use the definite, indefinite, or zero article before ***hope***. Without really affecting the meaning, so far as I'm concerned.